# Web Components: how to access child component instances from a parent

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

**EDIT** I've left out some details in this question, but assume that both of these elements **are already defined**. Also, in the real world problem, the DOM tree is bigger and the child component is **slotted** into the parent. There's no issue with finding the child component.

I have two web components: `Parent` and `Child`.

I might use these components in markup like this:

```html
<parent-element>
  <child-element></child-element>
</parent-element>
```

The `Child` component has logic I want to expose to the parent.

```js
class Child extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  publicMethod() {
    console.log('call me from the parent component');
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to call the child method from the parent like this:

```js
class Parent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  someTrigger() {
    const child = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('child-element');
    child.publicMethod();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, though, since `child` is an `HTMLElement`, because the `querySelector()` API returns an `HTMLElement` and not the web component *instance*.

Is there a way I can get the component's instance in a similar fashion? I'd like to be able to traverse the `Parent` components shadow tree to find a specific component instance.

Comment: The  returned HTMLElement **is** an instance with ``publicmethod``

Comment: Any HTML element has an attribute `.children`, which is an array which each element points to each of it's children and an attribute `.parentNode` which points to the parent node, Doesn't it works for you?

Comment: Your first 3 HTML lines show your ``<child-element>`` is in **lightDOM**, even when slotted it does NOT exist in shadowDOM. Create a full working (or failing) example with the [ < > ] button in the SO editor, we can play with.

Comment: ``.children`` will be an empty nodeList when the ``connectedCallback`` runs, because the ``connectedCallback`` runs on the opening tag, its children have NOT been parsed yet. (unless you **define** your Web Component **after** all DOM was parsed.. but then your Web Component will fail when others use it properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with `whenDefined`;
it tells you the Web Component was **defined**, NOT when it was **parsed** in the DOM:

As long as you keep the `<child-element>` in **lightDOM**, `<slot>` and shadowDOM have nothing to do with them.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important;top:0;zoom:.88}
.as-console-row:nth-child(n-6) {background:#0057B7!important;color:#FFD500!important}
.as-console-row:nth-child(n+6) {background:#FFD500!important;color:#0057B7!important}
.as-console-row-code{padding:0!important}
```

```html
<script>
  console.clear();
  class Component extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(this.nodeName, "constructor")
    }
    connectedCallback(){
      console.log("connectedCallback", this.nodeName, this.children.length, "children");      
    }
  }
  customElements.define("child-component", class extends Component {
    foo() {
      console.log("Executed <child-element>.foo()");
    }
  });
  customElements.define("parent-component", class extends Component {
    connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback();
      customElements.whenDefined('child-component')
                    .then(() => console.log("Promise resolved, <child-component> IS defined!"));
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till lightDOM is parsed
        console.log("After setTimeout",this.nodeName,"has", this.children.length, "children");
        this.querySelectorAll("child-component").forEach(child => child.foo());
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<parent-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Comment: From OP's question: *This doesn't work, though, since child is an HTMLElement*. So their issue is not having no access to this element. Otherwise the error they'd get would be something along the lines of `cannot call publicMethod of null`. For slots, I'd expect (haven't tested though) that only parsed nodes get slotted, and if they haven't yet been slotted at that point, the querySelector won't find it anyway.